# Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 5, shapes: [?,32,13,13,64], [3,3,64,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to fit my model for a different set of images that it was built for. Unfortunately, I am getting an error:
I know that there are a lot of these on the internet, but I am not sure where I can specify the argument that would fix that.

Thank you for your help!

```
Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 5 for '{{node separable_conv2d_78/separable_conv2d/depthwise}} = DepthwiseConv2dNative[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]](Placeholder, separable_conv2d_78/separable_conv2d/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,32,13,13,64], [3,3,64,1].
```

Any help would be appreciated!

```
input = Input(shape = (32, 50, 50, 3))
x = entry_flow(input)
x = middle_flow(x)
output = exit_flow(x)

model = Model (inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

Comment: Is 32 fixed batch size?

Comment: Yes, if I change my input from Input(shape = (32, 50, 50, 3) to Input(shape = (32, 50, 50), the code runs.

Comment: It seems like you don't need to define fixed batch size, it will be inferred.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code?

Comment: Oh, that works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> After changing input from `Input(shape = (32, 50, 50, 3)` to
> `Input(shape = (32, 50, 50)` the code runs (paraphrased from Tommy Tomsia)